# how to not save duplicate information in Customize?

Tags: customize

On a fresh install of emacs, I loaded my personal init files with all my custom lisp code. Then I changed one setting using the Customize interface and saved my changes. But in the `custom.el` file, Customize saved not just that one change, but all non default states. So now I have a `custom.el` file filled with information that's redundant with my own personal init file. This makes it tedious to look through my `custom.el` file to see settings I've changed.

Is this default behavior? Is there any way to direct Customize to save only the changes I make through the Customize interface?

Comment: How are you setting things in your init file? Are you using e.g. `setq`, or are you using `customize-set-value`? Also, how did you save your changes through the Customize interface? Did you change one setting and use  `Save for Future Sessions`, or something else?

Comment: My init file contains both `setq` and `custom-set-variables`. In Customize, I use `C-x C-s` Save all settings in buffer? `y`.

Comment: Do you happen to call `load-theme`? I was just tracking down an issue where customizations made to the current session before loading a theme end up getting saved to my custom-file.

Comment: @glucas yes I do. I almost always load one custom theme or another. Do you think that's the problem?

Comment: Just curious, but is there some reason you prefer using `setq` and `customize-set-value` in your init files? I personally prefer to have as much as possible set by customize in `custom.el`.

Comment: Because I have so many customizations that I break them down by category using org-babel. Easier to find and change things. http://sachachua.com/blog/2012/06/literate-programming-emacs-configuration-file/

Comment: +1 for @TreborRude's comment. Let Customize manage  variable  and face **type-checking**, **initialization**, and **update trigger actions**. Make Customize keep all of the settings it manages in the value of variable `custom-file` -- a *separate file from your init file*. (Anything else is silly, IMO.)

Comment: Personally, I use Customize for most things but it doesn't allow for conditional (machine- or OS-specific) settings unless you maintain near-duplicate custom files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen similar behavior when using `load-theme`. I'm not yet sure if this is an Emacs bug.

The behavior I see is as follows:

- Start Emacs, and customize one or more variables for the current session. I've tried this using `customize-set-variable` in my init file, as well as using the Easy Customization interface and `Set for Current Session`.
- Load a theme.
- Customize another option and this time `Save for Future Sessions`.

The result of this sequence is that all the options that I intended to be set only for the current session get written out to the custom file. The act of loading a theme somehow marks them to be saved. You can test this by loading your theme before making other customizations.

This strikes me as wrong, though I am not very familiar with the Emacs theme mechanism. I intend to verify this in a clean environment and file an Emacs bug.

**Update**

OK, I can reproduce this with a clean environment. Since this issue involves saving customizations you cannot test with `emacs -Q` (which disables saving changes), so I tested by starting Emacs 24.4 with an empty user home directory.

Then:

- `M-x customize-variable user-full-name`; set some value; `Set for Current Session`.
- `M-x load-theme deeper-blue`
- `M-x customize-variable user-mail-address`; set some value; `Save for Future Sessions`. 
  This results in a new `.emacs` file that includes both `user-full-name` and `user-mail-address`, even though the name should have only been set for the current session.

Submitted [bug #21355](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21355).

Comment: I guess it's hard to tell what's causing it. I'm trying out Spacemacs (hence the fresh install). Spacemacs loads a color theme by default when Emacs stars. Just now I tried wiping out the customizations file, restarting, using Customize to change a font face, then save, and... I got another fully populated customizations file.